# Keep two projects up to date on Git

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge, git-bash, git-fork

I’m making a Firefox fork and I wanted to know if it was possible to keep my custom changes to the Firefox code on GitHub but anything other than my own changes off GitHub.

For example:

A make a file called `foo.txt` on repository `A`, and repository `B` has a bunch of files with similar names like: `bar.txt`.

Now I want to have repository `B`’s files on my machine locally so I can compile my program with `foo.txt` and `bar.txt`, I want to keep `foo.txt` on GitHub but `bar.txt` should go into GitHub.

If I were to then add `bar.txt` to repository `A` in the future, I want repo A’s version of bar.txt to be used instead of repo B’s.

I want to be able to keep up to date with repo A files and repo B files and resolving any conflicts between the two.

I hope you understand what I mean by this.
Thanks.

Comment: `git merge` and `git rebase` may be of help to you here

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge and https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing

Comment: Thanks, i’ll try this